# Code not copied everything after git clone in Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: git, digital-ocean

I am trying to publish my code in a droplet in the Digital Ocean. I really don't have an idea what I am doing. I successfully installed phpmyadmin, LAMP Stack.

Then following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R15Jj2zs1z0. I cloned my git repo using this command in the droplet:

```
root@user:/var/www/<foldername># git clone git@github.com:gitsuername/gtirepo.git
```

This is based on the youtube tutorial link above.

However, not everything was copied. As per the image below the folders are in there. I checked the controllers and models are there as well:

[image]

My public folder was empty even my `.env` files are not carried over. The two files here are the ones I created manually in the droplet.
[image]

I know I am missing something but I don't know what it is can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Plz make your question more clear.  How you do it, and what the process outputed?

Comment: Generally `.env`s are not committed to repos as they contain credentials. Are you the only developer on this project? It is not clear what was copied over or how you copied the data over. Please add more details to the question. If you are not the only developer perhaps there is a readme with details for how to do deployments?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  There is no info here for us to have any idea what went wrong or how to help.  We need to see what you did, what responses, if any, you got, etc. 
 "*I cloned my git repo to the droplet*" - OK, how did you do that? 
 What did you type, and what response did you see? Please have a read of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: hi @LF00 I updated my question  my apologies.

Comment: Hi @user3783243, I am a student and I am the only developer. I have updated my question, provided some screenshots and the git line of code I ran to clone my git repo.

Comment: Check if the edited file is in your .gitignore file. If not, check if the git clone is success?

Comment: You've also to check if the file in track by git.